# 02 ranger 3.0 4x4 auto trans 104,000 miles Possible drivetrain noise? Whining when coasting to a stop

Tags: ford, noise, transmission, ranger, drivetrain

Just did a lot of work to this truck, have had it 6 months now an motor is great and trans shifts as it should. Have done 2 oil changes on it every 3,000 miles 5w30 high mileage conventional, replaced camshaft synchro, harmonic balancer, plugs wires coilpack, all new brakes an fromt end suspension an new exhaust manifold y pipe an 2 new cats. So 3 days after getting it back, this whine noise started, only when coasting to a stop up to about 10mph same rythem as rpm, and when i go from a stop it does it up to 10mph then i dont hear it again. Happens every time. Please i need help im thinking the worst

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like the rear differential is whining. Have you checked the fluid levels in it?

Comment: Yea when i had it in shop getting suspension done i asked him to check and fill if needed both differentials, this morning when i went to store it wasnt doing it, first time that i noticed it hasnt done it.

Comment: Well scratch that, it came back lol someome said possibly spider gear in differential?